# ubuntu-server 1.361.1 pulls open-vm-tools as dependency

Tags: server, package-management

Performed apt-get dist-upgrade on my Ubuntu server 16.04.4 LTS.
It updated ubuntu-server from version 1.361 to 1.361.1
As a result, open-vm-tools were installed as dependency.

So far I am failing to find any background for this. My server is not virtual.
Changelog is not really helpful:

```
root@ver:/var/log/apt# zcat /usr/share/doc/ubuntu-server/changelog.gz | head
ubuntu-meta (1.361.1) xenial; urgency=medium

  * Refreshed dependencies
  * Added s390-tools to server [s390x] LP: #1730647
```

Is it now assumed that every ubuntu server is a Vmware guest? What about bare metal and other hypervisors? Are they not expected to use this meta package anymore?

Thanks

Comment: `ubuntu-server` is an optional meta package and is unnecessary for a server install. It contains a number of packages the developers assume most users would want as an option. If you prefer, remove the meta package and any other packages you do not want.

Comment: Thanks @Panther.  I can certainly remove the open-vm-tools and this meta package will go with it. My point is that I am not aware to select it myself when installing, IMO it was there by default and I was happy with it so far.  What I am trying to understand now is some background that could lead the Ubuntu devs to include this vmware specific package into a meta package for more generic use.

Comment: It is a good question, if you don't get an answer here perhaps the mailing list?